# Am I missing a cast with querySelector('#element')?

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't find identical answer to my question, so I decided to ask it by myself.
Im trying to select a HTML element with a specified ID in it.

This version works fine.

```
var button = document.getElementById('#submit');

function doSmth(){
    console.log("clicked");
}

button.addEventListener('click', doSmth);
```

If I try to run the same code with querySelector:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#submit');
```

I get the following output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: button.addEventListener is not a function
```

Any ideas why same code outputs different return values?

This is the submit input field. It is part of the div container

```
<input id="#submit" type="submit">
```

Comment: does your `id` attribute have a `#` in it? - Your first version shouldn't work unless your id has a `#` prefixing it...

Comment: `document.getElementById('#submit')` wouldn't work unless your id had a literal `#` in it, ie `id="#submit"`

Comment: With querySelctor the `#` means find the element with the _id_ of "submit", whereas with getElementById, you already know you're looking for an id (as that's all getElementById can look for), so it looks for the element with the id matching `#submit`

Comment: Thank you @NickParsons , I just had to remove the # from my input tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the id have `#` use `\\` to escape it

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#\\#submit');

function doSmth() {
  console.log("clicked");
}

button.addEventListener('click', doSmth);
```

```html
<input id="#submit" type="submit">
```